# .env variable returns null for a single composer package

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-artisan

We use multiple packages, but **for a single one**, I get this error, only after i run `config:cache` : 'You need to specify your username and password in your .env file'

After i run `config:clear` the package works as intended and can read the env values.

We don't use `env('<package>_USER')` / `env('<package>_password')` anywhere in our code, **only the vendor file uses it**:

```
    function call_api_action($method, $params, $authenticate = true)
    {
        $this->username = env("<package>_USER", null);
        $this->password = env("<package>_PASSWORD", null);
        ...
```

What is the best way to fix this?

I'm thinking of overwriting `env("<package>_USER", null)` with something like `` config(`services.<package>.user`) ``, but **what would be the cleanest way to do this without modifing vendor files?**

Comment: When you cache the config laravel will no longer reads the .env file. You can either contact the package vendor to let them know (since this is likely an issue on their end) or you can specify those values as environment variables (which can get complicated if you want them to work both on the CLI and on web requests)

Comment: 100% vendor fault, use another package if you can't wait for a fix, or go to the github package and create a PR fixing the issue. Another super fast solution is to fork the package repo and fix it and use your own package until they fix their own